# 2-Dimensional Array Reduction

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional array where I need to convert the first diagonal numbers to zero.  For example, I need to convert the following:

```
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 5 9 5 ]
[ 3 2 1 ]
```

To this, meaning the diagonal `1 9 1` is now `0 0 0`:

```
[ 0 2 3 ]
[ 5 0 5 ]
[ 3 2 0 ]
```

How can I efficiently do this in C#?

Comment: Please check the next answer !!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're doing is setting the points in the grid to be zero when X and Y are equal. (1,1), (2,2), and so on;

```
int x = 4, y = 5;
int[,] array = new int[x,y]; // assume we initialize this with some values
for (int i = 0; i < x && i < y; i++ ) {
    array[i,i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This will work but i  need more optimized means by using LINQ or any other new things

Comment: peter, this IS about as optimized as you can get. New technologies like LINQ will generally only make things easier, not faster.